# Is it possible to explicitly define a swagger method upfront using swashbuckle for aspnetcore?

Tags: swagger, identityserver4, swashbuckle

I am currently using identityserver middleware in my project to implement an oauth service. I would like to use swagger to define some of the methods available in this middleware such as */Connect/Token* which is used to acquire and access token.

Unfortunately since this is middleware I do not have implementations of controllers that handle the http requests - since the requests are handled in the middleware.

Is it possible to explicitly define upfront a swaggerdoc with all the endpoint information (such as url, params etc) if you are using a middleware that handles all http requests?

Comment: Do you have a sample project somewhere you can share? If not can you create one on GitHub?

Comment: @HelderSepu [link](https://github.com/alexcothron/swagger_oauth/blob/master/Startup.cs)'github project'

Comment: Sorry I can't build that project getting a ton of errors like:  Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 2.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

Comment: My idea was to try with a DocumentFilter, we need to register all types involved in  the methods you require and add the paths to those methods... I wanted to give a precise example but I could not build that project. I have some samples of DocumentFilter here: https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L485

Comment: @HelderSepu Thanks for trying. You need to have the core 2.0 sdk installed. You should be able to run "dotnet restore" and "dotnet publish -r win10-x64" to get an executable that you can run. Also, I use the vs code ide.

Comment: Are you trying to have swagger document the IdentityServer4 exposed methods?

Comment: @aaronR yes the service endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a method for dynamically generating swagger documentation for the identityserver endpoints.

However as a workaround I created a manual swagger.json file using the [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/). I was able to export a swagger.json file from the editor. I added the file to my application and was able generate the swagger ui with the following code.

```
// serve static files
app.UseStaticFiles();

// id server middleware
app.UseIdentityServer();

// points to my static swagger.json file
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
   c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger.json", "My API");
});
```